# Index a numpy array using a tuple (or list) when len < ndim?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a 3d numpy array, eg:

```
>>> A = np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)
```

I want to take a 1d slice along axis 0 based on a pair of coordinates for axes 1 and 2:

```
>>> h = 1
>>> l = 2
>>> A[:,h,l]
array([ 6, 18])
```

So far so good. But what if my coordinate pair is stored as a tuple or a list, rather than two integers? I've experimented with a few obvious options, to no avail:

```
>>> coords = (1,2)
>>> A[coords]
array([20, 21, 22, 23])
>>> A[:,coords]
array([[[ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
>>> A[...,coords]
array([[[ 1,  2],
        [ 5,  6],
        [ 9, 10]],

       [[13, 14],
        [17, 18],
        [21, 22]]])
```

I've googled around on this and not found anything, but it's entirely possible that I'm not searching with the appropriate jargon. So, apologies if this is an overly simplistic question!

Comment: You'll need to unpack your coords into two separate arrays, one for each of the last two axes.  E.g. `h, l = coords`.  (Note that `coords` could be two-dimensional, in this case.)  Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can construct the slice tuple directly, with something like:

```
In [11]: A[(slice(None),) + coords]
Out[11]: array([ 6, 18])
```

---

This is because calling `A[:, 1, 2]` is equivalent / calls:

```
In [12]: A.__getitem__((slice(None, None, None), 1, 2))
Out[12]: array([ 6, 18])
```

Comment: Just on a side note to the OP: it does strictly have to be a tuple of slices, not just any iterable.  Numpy will interpret an array or list passed in in an entirely different manner.  Nice explanation, as well!

Comment: The caution about using tuples is good.  However, `ind=[slice(None)]*3; ind[1:]=coords; A[ind]` works just as well.  There's a note in http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html about this retaining backward compatibility with old numeric package (for a list containing a slice).